# How can i show flipbook when user clicks on flipbook's icons in jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Hope you all are fine. I Stuck in one problem from last three days and can't understand what should i do. If you can kindly help me. This is my code when user click on publication button a carousel of images become shown in the screen and when user click on these images it becomes filpbook of that images. The Problem in that is it works fine in first time and when user close that open flipbook and want to open new flipbook that old one still there and new clickable flipbook's icon didn't open in form of flipbook. I hope you people understand my question what i want to ask ? I also attached some images of results and also paste code so that you could relate to it.
[Image Carousel (flipbook's icon)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qlmr.png)
[flipbook open as expected when user click on it first time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9Isg.png)
[Image Carousel (flipbook's icon) User want to open new flipbook from carousel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBORR.png)
[New flipbook open but old flipbook didn't disappear it still open. New Flipbook should open instead of old one and hide old one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPc5A.png)

```js
   
            $(document).ready(function() {
                getPdfsIcons()
                $("#back").hide();
                // Load the HTML4 version if there's not CSS transform
                // $("#flipview").hide();
                //   var carousel = $("#carousel").slidingCarousel({
                //  squeeze: 100
                // });
                $("#back").click(function() {
                    $("#flipview").hide();
                    $("#carousel").hide();
                    $("#pub").hide();
                    $("#switch-field").hide();
                    $("#close-btn").hide();
                    loadMain();
                });
                $("#close-btn").hide();
            });
    
            function getPdfsIcons() {
                var dir;
                var choosenlanguage = $("input[type='radio']:checked").val();
    
                if (choosenlanguage == "e")
                    dir = "assets/Publications/English/";
                else if (choosenlanguage == "a")
                    dir = "assets/Publications/Arabic/";
                else if (choosenlanguage == "f")
                    dir = "assets/Publications/French/";
    
                var fileextension = ".jpg";
                var inc = 0;
    
                $.ajax({
                    url: dir,
                    success: function(data) {
                        $(data)
                            .find("a:contains(" + fileextension + ")")
                            .each(function(i) {
    
                                var filename = this.href
                                    .replace(window.location.host, "")
                                    .replace("http://", "");
                                var folder = filename;
                                $(".carousel").append(
                                    "<div id='slide" + i + "' class='slide'  onClick=getAllrecords(document.getElementById('slide" + i + "').style.opacity,'" + folder.replace("assets/Publications/English/", "").replace(".jpg", "").replace("/", "") + "','" + i + "');><p><a href='#'> <img src=" + filename + "> </a> <span> " + filename + " </span>  </p></div>" + "</div>"
    
                                );
                            });
                    },
                });
    
    
    
            }
    
    
    
            function getAllrecords(opacity, foldername, x) {
                if (opacity == 1) {
    
                    var choosenlanguage = $("input[type='radio']:checked").val();
    
                    if (choosenlanguage == "e")
                        dir = "assets/Publications/English/" + foldername + "/";
                    else if (choosenlanguage == "a")
                        dir = "assets/Publications/Arabic/" + foldername + "/";
                    else if (choosenlanguage == "f")
                        dir = "assets/Publications/French/" + foldername + "/";
                    var fileextension = ".jpg";
                    $.ajax({
                        url: dir,
                        success: function(data) {
                            $(data)
                                .find("a:contains(" + fileextension + ")")
                                .each(function(i) {
    
                                    var filename = this.href
                                        .replace(window.location.host, "")
                                        .replace("http://", "");
                                    $(".flipbook-pages").append("<div class='flipImgs" + x + "'><img  src='" + filename + "' width='600' height='600'  /></div>");
    
    
                                    $(".flipbook-thumbnail").append(
                                        "<li>" +
                                        "<img class='page-" +
                                        ++i +
                                        "' src='" +
                                        filename +
                                        "' width='200' height='200' ' />" +
                                        "</li>"
                                    );
                                });
    
                        },
                    });
    
                    $("#flipview").show();
                    $("#carousel").hide();
                    $("#pub").hide();
                    $("#switch-field").hide();
                    $("#close-btn").show();
    
    
                    $("#close-btn")
    
                    .click(function() {
                        //window.location.href = "home.html"
                        $("#flipview").hide();
                        //$(".mainmenu_row1").hide()
                        //$(".mainmenu_row2").hide()
                        $("#pub").show();
                        $("#carousel").show();
                        //$(".flipbook-pages").empty();
                        //$(".flipbook-thumbnail").empty();
                        // var rangeObj = new Range();
                        // // Select all of theParent 's children
                        // rangeObj.selectNodeContents(document.getElementById('flipbook-pages'));
                        // // Delete everything that is selected
                        // rangeObj.deleteContents();
    
                    });
                    yepnope({
                        test: Modernizr.csstransforms,
                        yep: ["assets/js/turn.min.js"],
                        nope: ["assets/js/turn.html4.min.js"],
                        both: [
                            "assets/css/basic.css",
                            "assets/css/magazine.css",
                            "assets/js/magazine.js",
                        ],
                        complete: loadApp,
                    });
                }
            }
    
            function loadApp() {
                // Create the flipbook
    
                $(".flipbook-pages").turn({
                    // Width
    
                    width: 922,
    
                    // Height
    
                    height: 600,
    
                    // Elevation
    
                    elevation: 50,
    
                    // Enable gradients
    
                    gradients: true,
    
                    // Auto center this flipbook
    
                    autoCenter: true,
                });
                $(".thumbnails").click(function(event) {
                    var page;
    
                    if (
                        event.target &&
                        (page = /page-([0-90]+)/.exec($(event.target).attr("class")))
                    ) {
                        $(".flipbook-pages").turn("page", page[1]);
                    }
                });
    
                $(".next-button")
                    .bind("mouseover", function() {
                        $(this).addClass("next-button-hover");
                    })
                    .click(function() {
                        $(".flipbook-pages").turn("next");
                    });
    
                $(".previous-button")
                    .bind("mouseover", function() {
                        $(this).addClass("previous-button-hover");
                    })
                    .click(function() {
                        $(".flipbook-pages").turn("previous");
                    });
            }
    
    
            function loadMain() {
                window.location.href = "home.html";
                //   $("icon_1").removeClass("animate__fadeOut");
                //   // $("icon_2").removeClass("animate__fadeOut");
                //   // $("icon_3").removeClass("animate__animated animate__swing animate__fadeOut");
                //   // $("icon_4").removeClass("animate__animated animate__swing animate__fadeOut");
                //   // $("icon_5").removeClass("animate__animated animate__swing animate__fadeOut");
                //   // $("icon_6").removeClass("animate__animated animate__swing animate__fadeOut");
    
    
    
    
    
                //   document.getElementById("icon_1").classList.add("animate__animated animate__swing animate__fadeIn");
                // document.getElementById("icon_3").classList.add("animate__animated animate__swing animate__fadeIn");
                // document.getElementById("icon_4").classList.add("animate__animated animate__swing animate__fadeIn");
                // document.getElementById("icon_5").classList.add("animate__animated animate__swing animate__fadeIn");
                // document.getElementById("icon_6").classList.add("animate__animated animate__swing animate__fadeIn");
                // document.getElementById("icon_2").classList.add("animate__animated animate__swing animate__fadeIn");
    
            }
    
            function onBounce(id) {
    
                document.getElementById(id).classList.add("animate__bounceOut");
                if (id = "icon_2") {
                    getPdfsIcons();
    
                    document.getElementById("icon_1").classList.add("animate__fadeOut");
                    document.getElementById("icon_3").classList.add("animate__fadeOut");
                    document.getElementById("icon_4").classList.add("animate__fadeOut");
                    document.getElementById("icon_5").classList.add("animate__fadeOut");
                    document.getElementById("icon_6").classList.add("animate__fadeOut");
    
                    document.getElementById(id).addEventListener('animationend', () => {
                        // document.getElementById("mainmenu").style.setProperty('--animate-duration', '0.1s');
                        // document.getElementById("mainmenu").classList.add("animate__fadeOut");
    
                        document.getElementById("pub").style.setProperty('display', 'block');
                        document.getElementById("pub").classList.add("animate__zoomInRight");
                        $("#back").show();
                        var carousel = $("#carousel").slidingCarousel({
                            squeeze: 100
                        });
                        // do something animate__zoomInRight
                    });
                    $(".carousel").append(
                        "<div class='navigate-left'><img src='assets/images/backward.png' /></div>" +
                        "<div class='navigate-right'><img src='assets/images/forward.png' /></div>"
                    );
                }
    
            }
    
    
    
            function language(lang) {
                if (lang == 0) {
                    document.getElementById('icon_1').style.backgroundImage = "url('assets/images/ebv1.png')";
    
                    document.getElementById('icon_2').style.backgroundImage = "url('assets/images/ebv2.png')";
                    document.getElementById('icon_3').style.backgroundImage = "url('assets/images/ebv4.png')";
                    document.getElementById('icon_4').style.backgroundImage = "url('assets/images/ebv5.png')";
                    document.getElementById('icon_5').style.backgroundImage = "url('assets/images/ebv6.png')";
                    document.getElementById('icon_6').style.backgroundImage = "url('assets/images/ebv7.png')";
    
    
                } else if (lang == 1) {
                    document.getElementById('icon_1').style.backgroundImage = "url('assets/images/abv1.png')";
    
                    document.getElementById('icon_2').style.backgroundImage = "url('assets/images/abv2.png')";
                    document.getElementById('icon_3').style.backgroundImage = "url('assets/images/abv4.png')";
                    document.getElementById('icon_4').style.backgroundImage = "url('assets/images/abv5.png')";
                    document.getElementById('icon_5').style.backgroundImage = "url('assets/images/abv6.png')";
                    document.getElementById('icon_6').style.backgroundImage = "url('assets/images/abv7.png')";
                } else if (lang == 2) {
                    document.getElementById('icon_1').style.backgroundImage = "url('assets/images/fbv1.png')";
    
                    document.getElementById('icon_2').style.backgroundImage = "url('assets/images/fbv2.png')";
                    document.getElementById('icon_3').style.backgroundImage = "url('assets/images/fbv4.png')";
                    document.getElementById('icon_4').style.backgroundImage = "url('assets/images/fbv5.png')";
                    document.getElementById('icon_5').style.backgroundImage = "url('assets/images/fbv6.png')";
                    document.getElementById('icon_6').style.backgroundImage = "url('assets/images/fbv7.png')";
                }
            }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/animate.min.css" />
    
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/experiment.css" />
    
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/jquery.ui.css">
        </link>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/default.css">
        </link>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
        <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/modernizr.2.5.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/hash.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/turn.html4.js"></script>
    
        <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/zoom.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/scissor.min.js"></script>
    
        <script src="assets/js/jquery-slidingCarousel.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/sliding-carousel.css" />
    
        <!-- <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json" /> -->
        <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#ffffff" />
        <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="/ms-icon-144x144.png" />
        <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff" />
        <!-- <script src="assets/js/app.js"></script> -->
        <title>Interactive Apps</title>
    
        <style>
            .scrollmenu {
                background-color: white;
                overflow: auto;
                white-space: nowrap;
            }
            
            .scrollmenu li {
                display: inline-block;
                color: white;
                padding: 14px;
                text-decoration: none;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div class="fullscreen">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="logo">
                    <img src="assets/images/logo.png" alt="logo image" />
                </div>
    
                <div id="switch-field" class="switch-field">
                    <input type="radio" id="radio-three" onclick="language(0);" name="langchoice" value="e" checked />
                    <label for="radio-three">English</label>
                    <input type="radio" id="radio-four" name="langchoice" onclick="language(1);" value="a" />
                    <label for="radio-four">عربى</label>
                    <input type="radio" id="radio-five" name="langchoice" onclick="language(2);" value="f" />
                    <label for="radio-five">Français</label>
                </div>
    
                <div class="pole-clock">
                    <div id="clock">
                        <div id="hour"><img src="assets/images/small_hand.png" /></div>
                        <div id="minute"><img src="assets/images/long_hand.png" /></div>
                        <div id="second"><img src="assets/images/sec_hand.png" /></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="footer">
                <img src="assets/images/Path 60.png" alt="footer image" />
            </div>
            <div id="mainmenu" class="animate__animated">
                <div class='mainmenu_row1'>
                    <div id="icon_1" class='menu1 animate__animated animate__swing' onclick="onBounce('icon_1');">
    
                    </div>
                    <div id="icon_2" class='menu2  animate__animated animate__swing' onclick="onBounce('icon_2');">
    
                    </div>
                    <div id="icon_3" class='menu3 animate__animated animate__swing' onclick="onBounce('icon_3');"> </div>
                </div>
                <div class='mainmenu_row2'>
                    <div id="icon_4" class='menu4 animate__animated animate__swing' onclick="onBounce('icon_4');"> </div>
                    <div id="icon_5" class='menu5 animate__animated animate__swing' onclick="onBounce('icon_5');"> </div>
                    <div id="icon_6" class='menu6 animate__animated animate__swing' onclick="onBounce('icon_6');"> </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    
            <!-- publications -->
            <div id="pub" style="display: none;" class="pub animate__animated">
                <div id="carousel" class="carousel">
    
                </div>
    
    
            </div>
            <div id="flipview" class="flipview">
                <div class="flipbook-viewport">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="flipbook">
                            <div id="flipbook-pages" class="flipbook-pages" style="margin-top: -8rem">
                                <div ignore="1" class="next-button"></div>
                                <!-- Previous button -->
                                <div ignore="1" class="previous-button"></div>
                            </div>
                            <button type="button" class="btn close" id="close-btn" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                  <span aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: -webkit-xxx-large">×</span>
                </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="thumbnails" style="padding-top: 44rem">
                    <div>
                        <ul class="flipbook-thumbnail scrollmenu"></ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    
            <div id="back" class="back"></div>
        </div>
    
    
 
    
    </body>
    
    </html>
```